# Web Driver does not wait for the specified time limit when checking for the invisibility of an element

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriverwait

I have this class named ReusableFunctions that I use to implement methods that are commonly used like checking for the presence of elements or invisibility of elements. I have declared all these methods as static and invoke them using the class name in my test class. I have methods that wait for a default period of time (20 seconds in my case) and also methods that take in a time value as its parameter and wait for the specified time period. The problem is that even though I pass parameters into my wait methods WebDriver discards the parameter value and just waits for the default time of 20 seconds.I have logs printed in my console and I see that even though I have passed a time parameter value of 10 seconds web driver discards that and waits for a time period of 20 seconds. Please refer to the code below to understand this better.

```
//The reusable class where i implement my wait methods

public class ReusableFunctions extends InitializeBrowser{

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ReusableFunctions.class);

//A general wait method that waits for 20 seconds before throwing an 
exception

public static void waitTillElementDisappears(WebElement we){

   WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(we));
}

//A wait method that takes in a parameter value and waits for the 
specified time limit

public static boolean 
waitTillElementDisappearsWithCustomizedWaitParameter(WebElement we, long 
timeValue){

    WebDriverWait waitTillInvisibility=new WebDriverWait(driver, 
    timeValue);

    waitTillInvisibility.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(we));

    if(!we.isDisplayed()){

        return true;

    }else{

        return false;
    }
}
}


//This is how I write validation methods using the above wait 
implementations

public void clickEditInCommunityList(){

    log.info("Clicking edit button in the community list section");

    ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO,"Clicking edit button in 

    the community list section");

    try{

        if(errorMessageBox.isDisplayed()){

   ReusableFunctions.waitTillElementDisappearsWithCustomizedWaitParameter

   (errorMessageBox,10);

        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        log.info("The exception is++++"+e);

        log.info("Error message box not displayed");

    }

    try{

        if(addBackgroundErrorMessage.isDisplayed()){


  ReusableFunctions.waitTillElementDisappears(addBackgroundErrorMessage);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        log.info("The exception is++++"+e);

        log.info("Error messages background not displayed");

    }

    communityEditButton.click();

    log.info("Edit button clicked successfully");

    ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.INFO,"Edit button clicked 

    successfully");
    }
```

As you can see from the above code in one try, catch block I have used the default wait function which waits for a period of 20 seconds and in the other try, catch block I have used the other wait function which takes in a time value of 10 seconds as its parameter. But when I run these tests what I see from my logs is that in both the try, catch blocks web driver waits for 20 seconds.

```
Logs below
05-07-2019 **15:39:38** INFO [SNMPPage]: Clicking edit button in the 
community list section
05-07-2019 **15:39:59** INFO [SNMPPage]: The exception 
is++++org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: 
waiting for invisibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 
'By.xpath: //ul[@id='noty_center_layout_container']' (tried for 10 
second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

The above log is what I get when the wait statement with the time parameter value is executed. You can see that it says 10 seconds but the time stamp value shows 20 seconds.

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `implicitWait` somewhere?

Comment: The only implicit wait I have set in my project is in the initialize browser class using the following statement  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is mixing `Implicit` and `Explicit` wait.

When you set ImplicitWait like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then you slow down driver actions like `findElement` which causes an additional 10 seconds delay. The outcome of mixing two different kind of waits is unpredictable.

Removing `implicitWait` will fix your case

**EDIT:**

From [Selenium docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits):

> WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits! Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

Comment: While the information in this answer is correct, I don't see any indication of the OP using an implicit wait in the information provided.

Comment: @Ardesco Read OP's comment under OP's question.

Comment: That actually did solve my problem. Changed the implicit wait in the initialize browser page with an explicit wait. See the fresh logs below

Comment: 05-07-2019 18:12:01 INFO [SNMPPage]: Clicking edit button in the community list section
05-07-2019 18:12:11 INFO [SNMPPage]: The exception is++++org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for invisibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //ul[@id='noty_center_layout_container']' (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Aha, I stand corrected.  @RahulNair it would be good to edit your question to add this critical bit of information in, comments don't always get seen.  Upvote added to this.

Comment: I would add that the [Selenium docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) specifically state NOT to mix implicit and explicit waits for just this reason, `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits! Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you run:

```
ReusableFunctions.waitTillElementDisappearsWithCustomizedWaitParameter(errorMessageBox,10);
```

and then

```
ReusableFunctions.waitTillElementDisappears(addBackgroundErrorMessage);
```

in sequence.

Both of these are Logging `log.info("The exception is++++"+e);` in the catch block.  What's the following log line, is it `Error messages background has disappeared`?  If so it looks like your code is working as expected.

You may want to tweak the lines that log the exception so that they better identify which line of code is actually logging.

Comment: I am sorry. That log message should actually be "Error background message not displayed". Editing my post.